# Package and distribute Bash script with NPM to allow installation globally into developer workstation's paths with npm install

Tags: node.js, bash, rest, automation, npm

I have some scripts that I want to distribute with npm for developers to be able to install globally on their workstations and then use the commands of the scripts on their computers in their development workflow.

I can't work out how to get npm to actually add the script in its package to the path though.

I see that the firebase tools have this in their package.json:

```
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "bin": {
    "firebase": "./bin/firebase"
  },
```

...but I can't quite work out how this relates to my project.

The first project I am trying to distribute with npm is for controlling a Belkin WeMo light switch, it includes an executable 'wemo' and an included functions.inc.sh file, this can be seen @ https://github.com/agilemation/Belkin-WeMo-Command-Line-Tools.git

If anyone can point me in the right direction it will be really appreciated!!!

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 4):

Any key/value pairs placed into the `bin` key of the `package.json` will be symlink'ed into the NPM bin-dir path.

The `key` is what you want the command to be named and the `value` part is the script in your package it should run.

Ergo, in your example, when `npm install` finishes running it'll create a symlink from `[package-install-path]/bin/firebase` to `/usr/local/bin/firebase` (or whatever bin directory prefix NPM is using (`npm bin -g` will tell you where this is).

If you only have one script you can also do:

```
{
  "name": "my-awesome-package",
  "bin": "./myscript.sh"
}
```

And it'll symlink `myscript.sh` to `my-awesome-package`

Although you should be wary of including bash scripts since they won't work on Windows.

Here are the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) for this.